# File not found error when it should create it (only when I add the current date to the name)

Tags: python, file, csv, date

I'm trying to create a `.csv` file with some **scraped** data that enters the function as the "results" argument. The problem is when i add the current system date to the name of the file, I get a "file not found error" when the result I expect is a file to be created.

Here's my code:

```py
def saveData(results):
    date = datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    file = pathlib.Path(f'Results-{date}.csv')
    with open(file,'w',newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for result in results:
            if result:
                writer.writerow(result)
        print('File written')


saveData(scrapedData(urlList()))
```

And the Error that I am getting:

```
line 99, in saveData
with open(file,'w',newline='') as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Results-13\\02\\2020.csv'
```

Please note that I do not get this error when I remove the date from the file name.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried escaping the forward slashes (`/`) in `strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`, which should give you `strftime('%d\/%m\/%Y')`?

Comment: @Ente I tried after your's and tupteq's answer and it solved it... so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have slashes (`/`) in your file name. They are converted to backslashes (you're probably a Windows user) and they are treated as path separators. So, `open()` tries to create a file deep in non existing directory tree.

Just replace slashes by some other character (avoid `*` and other special characters).

Comment: Other special characters to avoid:

< > : / \ | ? * and the double quote "

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved it! haha seems so obvious now!